# How to I get the protectedRangeId with google sheets api v4?

Tags: google-apps-script

My objective is to use the [updateProtectedRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#ProtectedRange) endpoint, to update an existing protected sheet.

My question is, how do I get the protectedRangeId in the first place?

I have this code so far?

```
const p = <target-sheet>.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentaiton more carefully, I found the properties using the `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get` method:

```js
const sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId()).sheets;

// here just the first sheet, and first range
const protectedRangeId = sheets[0].protectedRanges[0];
```